# Create asset inactivity alarm in Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I have a system where each device is connected to many sensors which monitors the temperature of different assets. So, I propagate the telemetry from the device to each related asset. That is fine. I also set up an inactivity alarm for the devices (following [this](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/create-inactivity-alarm/)). The device inactivity alarm triggers appropriately when a device becomes inactive.

Now, I am looking to establish an alarm for asset inactivity. Specifically, I want to trigger an alarm if a sensor becomes disconnected from its associated device, resulting in no data transmission to the asset for more than 15 minutes. In other words, I want to detect when the asset telemetry is not updated due to a sensor being disconnected. **How can I implement this functionality?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Generator node as a pulse clock and then compare timestamps. The algoritm would be as follows:

1. Set the `Generator` with your Asset as the originator and a short trigger period.
2. Then feed a green `OriginatorTelemetry` node to load the last telemetry of that asset as a string in the `metadata` object.
3. Feed a blue `TransformationScript` and/or a yellow `FilterScript` node.
4. In the script, parse the `ts` in the `metadata`, take the difference with JS `Date.now()` and compare it with your desired time threshold (15min=900000ms)
5. Handle as needed (Save timeseries, trigger alarm, email,...)

By the way, because it would be great to implement a more deep solution for this 'non-signals' events, in our company we have plans to include some hardware trigger for disconections in the future. This way, in case of a shut down in energy, a capacitor/battery/cell would release enough energy to send a msg with `{isDisconected : true}`.

Hope being of help.

Comment: Thanks @andresrokp. I think it is a good idea. The only problem I see is that I have to do that for each asset (and I have too many).... I was trying to find a more straight forward solution to monitor asset inactivity...

Comment: @betelgeuse check out the Entity Group option in the generator node. It can resolves to signal multiple devices or assets